# YoutubePlayer has only sound and media controllers, but no video

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

So, `YoutubePlayer` has sound and media controllers, but the `ImageView` that should show video content is not visible. In fact, Layout Inspector says it's `GONE`.

[image]

I have a `YoutubeFragment` that extends `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`.

I'm adding it to my activity as:

```
if (!youTubePlayer.isAdded) {
        val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.add(x.id, youTubePlayer, TAG)
        ft.commit()
}

youTubePlayer.view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

Player is visible - with controllers, but the image is gone. I believe that `ImageView` should be `VISIBILE`. How can I access this view and change it's visibility?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but finally figured it out. Basically, I had few views that overlapped YoutubePlayer. This should not happen, so you have to go through `Layout Inspector` and check wether you have any views that overlap with visibility `View.VISIBLE`. If you have any, just set them to `View.GONE` or if you have very complex layouts (some childrens might have visibility on) you can just use `removeView`.